# passing data from view to controller with ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I'm currently doing an application which uses ajax in getting user inputs from form fields then concatenate it in a string, this works fine but I'm getting a 
    "POST 500 (Internal Server Error")

and cannot pass the data. How do I pass a string from view to controller with ajax and access it in a controller.

Here are my codes:

the script

```
<script>
 // $(document).ready(function(){
 function saveData(){
 var con =  document.getElementById('tiks').value;
 // var dataString = {'conid':con};
  alert(con);
  var cct = $("input[name=csrf_token_name]").val();

  var base_url = <?php base_url(); ?>;

  $.ajax({
      url: base_url + "welcome/newShortestPath",
      type: "POST",
      data: {'conid':con, 'csrf_token_name':cct},
      success:function(){
        alert("SUCCESS KALUY-I   "+con);
        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
      }
  });
   }
```

controller

```
public function newShortestPath(){
    echo "REACHED";
    $var = $this->input->post('conid');
    //$this -> load -> model('edge_model');
    //$this->edge_model->setConstraints();

}
```

really need your help guys. thanks in advance. :)

UPDATE

Im no longer getting any error by fixing the errors at calling the base_url() function but at the same time I cant fetch the passed data, is there any other way fetching data from post to controller?

Comment: alert your ajax url, and check what the path is generating? then hit that path directly from your browser, Is that path is accessible?

Comment: how to alert it? is it like this? "alert(url)"? or different?

Comment: i tried.. and it returned "http://localhost/orient/index.php/welcome/newShortestPath" then i changed the url to this and its still the same thing though Im not getting the Internal Server Error but the newShortestPath controller is still not reached.

Answer (score 2):

you have to `echo` the `base_url` and wrap your var with `''`

```
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
```

**Update**

based on the error you are getting which is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url()

as you mentioned in your comment.

what you have to do is to go to `application/config/autoload.php`
and find

```
$autoload['helper'] = array();
```

then change it to

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

or manually load the `url` helper:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

read more [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: i did this but it gave me error. so i change it to direct url "http://localhost/orient/index.php/welcome/newShortestPath". but still it doesnt work.

Comment: Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function base_url() is the error

Comment: is there really a difference in accessing it via base_url and accessing it via direct url: "http://localhost/orient/index.php/welcome/newShortestPath"?

Comment: i tried your suggestion, it fixed the error by having "base_url + "index.php/welcome/newShortestPath" but it did not solve my main problem. I still cant reach my destination controller.

Comment: This was your error and  if there's another one just update your question accordingly with error message included.

Comment: @user2919049 - after executing, what does your console prints out? and what exactly you want to have back from your model? are you using firebug or any other developer tool to track your ajax post? what are you expecting in details? answer this question in an update in your answer so we can help you, otherwise we can't figure out anything.

Answer (score 0):

Tips:

Tip 1:
You can setup all url:

```
var url = <?php echo site_url('welcome/newShortestPath'); ?>;
```

Tip 2:
Use site_url() instead base_url(). base_url must be used to resources (img, css, js, etc.)
To build URL's use site_url()